# Optimize the Dutch telephone number RegEx pattern

Tags: regex

This is my current RegEx:

```
^((\+|00(\s|\s?\-\s?)?)31(\s|\s?\-\s?)?(\(0\)[\-\s]?)?|0)[1-9]((\s|\s?\-\s?)?[0-9])((\s|\s?-\s?)?[0-9])([0-9])\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]$
```

These are my test results:

- 0612345678          true
- 06-12345678         true
- +31612345678        true
- +316-12345678       true
- 00316-12345678      true
- 061234567           false
- 06-12-345678        false
- 06-asdfghjk         false
- 0331234567          true
- **0345-123456         false**
- +31331234567        true
- +3133-1234567       true
- 003133-1234567      true
- 033123456           false
- 010-12-34567        false
- 035-asdfghj         false
- 0345-123456         false
- 010-1234567         true

Everything seems ok, but there is one :-) string which needs to be matched (correct telephone number) but the RegEx doesn't match. This is the 0345-123456. Can anybody help me complete (or optimize) my RegEx so that all the above tests are ok?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

There are optional whitespace chars in the pattern, but in the example data there are no whitespace chars.

You could write a pattern to match the specific listed formats, and for a match only you can omit the capture groups.

Note that `0345-123456` is 2 times in the list.

```
^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)31|0)(?:\d-?\d{8}|\d\d-\d{7})|0\d{3}-\d{6})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:(?:\+|00)31|0)` Match either `+31` or `0031` or `0`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\d-?\d{8}` Match a digit, optional `-` and 8 digits
    - `|` Or
    - `\d\d-\d{7}` Match 2 digits `-` and 7 digits
  - `)` Close non capture group
  - `|` Or
  - `0` Match a single zero
  - `\d{3}-\d{6}` Match 3 digits `-` 6 digits
- `)` Close the outer non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HlPmJd/1)